# Check file existence without permissions request

Tags: android, permissions, android-fileprovider, runtime-permissions

I found that I can check file existence (method file.exist()) on Android 7 in external storage without permission request popup for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

I have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in manifest but I don't show permission popup. And when I do `file.exist()` I have no any exception. Of course I have exception when try read this file.

Is this normal behavior? Can I expect that this work same on another devices. As for me this is strange that I can check file existence without requesting user.

Comment: You can check file existence with File.exists(). It will probably return false even if the file exists. Thats all. You are not reading the file or writing to it if you use File.exists().

Comment: File.exist() return true if file exist and false if not exist